# Vue3 Higher Order Handler fails

Tags: vue.js

I have a higher order function `memberUpdate` defined as:

```js
const memberUpdate = (prop: string) => (evt: FocusEvent) => {
  console.log("made it", { prop, evt });
};
```

and then I want to use it in HTML like so:

```html
<p-input
  id="lastName"
  label="Last name"
  class="col-span-4"
  v-model:modelValue="lastName"
  @blur="memberUpdate('lastName')"
/>
```

However, doing this seems to just swallow the error. If I am more explicit, however, it works exactly as it should:

```html
<p-input
  id="firstName"
  label="First name"
  class="col-span-3"
  v-model:modelValue="firstName"
  @blur="(evt) => memberUpdate('firstName')(evt)"
/>
```

Interestingly, even though the this SFC has the language stated as being TypeScript (aka, `<script lang="ts">` it seems to cause unexpected behavior if I include Typescript in the template like so:

```html
<p-input
  id="firstName"
  label="First name"
  class="col-span-3"
  v-model:modelValue="firstName"
  @blur="(evt: FocusEvent) => memberUpdate('firstName')(evt)"
/>
```

This latter part may be a separate issue but it is unexpected considering the vs-code editor (with Vetur) does reveal typing information in the template section.

> Also please note that I am using the composition API, which means that in the TS code block I return `{ memberUpdate }`.

Comment: I'm almost positive you should be using `@blur="memberUpdate('firstName')($event)"`

Comment: and Typescript isn't supported in the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template compiler generates different code for event handlers depending on the event handler code.

If the handler is a simple property such as `handleBlur` then it will be set as the handler directly:

```html
<p-input @blur="handleBlur">
```

```js
h('p-input', {
  onBlur: handleBlur
})
```

However, let's say you want to set the event handler to the result of a function call that happens at render time. Because the handler is more complex (a function call) then it will be wrapped in a function for you transparently which *defers its evaluation until the event fires* (which is usually what you want 99% of the time):

```html
<p-input @blur="handleBlur('arg')">
```

```js
h('p-input', {
  onBlur: $event => handleBlur('arg')
})
```

That's what's happening here. Your event handler is essentially this:

```js
h('p-input', {
  onBlur: $event => memberUpdate('lastName')
})
```

But you want this, which isn't possible:

```js
h('p-input', {
  onBlur: memberUpdate('lastName')
})
```

So the only way to do it 100% in the template is to do what Derek suggested:

```html
<p-input @blur="memberUpdate('lastName')($event)">
```

```js
h('p-input', {
  onBlur: $event => memberUpdate('lastName')($event)
})
```

Unfortunately the generated code isn't optimal this way due to the extra function wrapper.

Comment: seems a bit magical but you're 100% right and I can live with it